# Write to file with register_shutdown_function

Tags: php, php-5.3

Is it possible to do the following?

```
register_shutdown_function('my_shutdown');
function my_shutdown ()
{
    file_put_contents('test.txt', 'hello', FILE_APPEND);
    error_log('hello', 3, 'test.txt');
}
```

Doesn't seem to work.
BTW i'm on PHP 5.3.5.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It depends which SAPI you are using. The [documentation page for register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) states that under certain servers, like Apache, the working directory of the script changes.

The file gets written, but not where your `.php` file is (*DocumentRoot*), but in the folder of the Apache server (*ServerRoot*).

To prevent this, you need to some sort of hotwire the working folder changes. Just when **your script starts executing** (in the first few lines), you need to somehow store the real working folder. Creating a constant with `define()` is perfect for this.

```
define('WORKING_DIRECTORY', getcwd());
```

And you need to modify the shutdown function part like this:

```
function my_shutdown ()
{
    chdir(WORKING_DIRECTORY);

    file_put_contents('test.txt', 'hello', FILE_APPEND);
    error_log('hello', 3, 'test.txt');
}

register_shutdown_function('my_shutdown');
```

This way, the working folder will instantly be changed back to the real one when the function is called, and the `test.txt` file will appear in the *DocumentRoot* folder.

*Some modification:* It is better to call `register_shutdown_function()` **after** the function has been declared. That's why I wrote it **below** the function code, not above it.

Comment: So, did this answer work? I hope I will hear about your results.

Comment: Does the Apache version matter? According to some of comments on the function documentation it seems so. I have two web servers and one works and the other doesn't. The one that does is Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) on a Mac. The other that doesn't is Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu) in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

check this: (from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php))

```
Note:

Working directory of the script can change inside the shutdown function 
under some web servers, e.g. Apache.
```

check it with `getcwd();`