# Shutdown handlers and relative paths

Tags: php, apache, relative-path

Create a PHP project that consist of 2 files - `index.php` that contains the code below and another file (in the same directory) called `example.png`.

```
echo file_exists('example.png')
    ? 'outside the handler - exists'
    : 'outside the handler - does not exist';

register_shutdown_function('handle_shutdown');

function handle_shutdown()
{
    echo file_exists('example.png')
        ? 'inside the handler - exists'
        : 'inside the handler - does not exist';
}

foo();
```

Run `index.php`.

Here's what you'll get:

```
outside the handler - exists
Fatal error: Call to undefined function foo() in /path/to/project/index.php on line 16
inside the handler - does not exist
```

Here's my question.

Why can't the inside `file_exists` (the one in the handler) find the file?

Comment: example.php or example.png?

Comment: That is commonly known to not work. You would need to use absolute paths in the shutdown phase of PHP. See the notes on http://php.net/register_shutdown_function

Comment: That may be a typo but from the output you can see that the same file exists check returns different values inside and outside the handle_shutdown function

Comment: @Rafael, It should be `example.png`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure why the reason, but the PHP documentation does warn of this in the note under `register_shutdown_function()` which states:

```
Note:

Working directory of the script can change inside the shutdown function under some web servers, e.g. Apache.
```

You might try echoing out `getcwd()` to get an idea as to what is actually happening.

Comment: Here's a link to a solution if the working directory does change. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861606/write-to-file-with-register-shutdown-function

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for the function,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

There is a note stating,

```
Working directory of the script can change inside the shutdown function under some web servers, e.g. Apache.
```

Answer (score 1):

On some SAPIs of PHP, in the shutdown function the working directory can change. See this note on the manual page of the [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function):

> Working directory of the script can change inside the shutdown function under some web servers, e.g. Apache.

A relative path is dependent on the working directory. With it changed, the file is not found any longer.

If you use an absolute path instead, you do not run into that problem:

```
$file = __DIR__ . '/' . 'example.png';

echo file_exists($file)
    ? 'outside the handler - exists'
    : 'outside the handler - does not exist';

$handle_shutdown = function() use ($file)
{
    echo file_exists($file)
        ? 'inside the handler - exists'
        : 'inside the handler - does not exist';
}

register_shutdown_function($handle_shutdown);
```