# PHP - Unable to find files inside of shutdown function

Tags: php, error-handling, shutdown

I'm trying to set up some error logging

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

but whenever I try to include a file inside of the shutdown function - it cannot be found, even though it exists and is included just fine throughout my application elsewhere

```
function shutdown()
{
    require_once LIB_DIR.'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
}
```

Gives me an error saying the file could not be found.. am I missing something here, does the relative path to a file change inside the shutdown function or something?

Comment: `register_shutdown_function` only registers a callback which is executed once the script finished. It doesnt make sense to include a library there.

Comment: I'm not directly including the file like that, It's being included inside of a factory class, I just simplified for the example. If I want to send off an email on a fatal error then what would you suggest I do?

Comment: Yes, registered shutdown functions can load files. I've just tested it with a simple test script based in yours. According to Occam's razor, if PHP cannot find the file, the file probably does not exist at such location.

Comment: "Yes, registered shutdown functions can load files" - OK, sorry, i didnt know that. I will retreat from this thread in shame.

Comment: Yeah so I'm confused as to why the file is included in any other place in the application apart from the shutdown function. The path is 100% correct..

Comment: Can you please share here what is within const `LIB_DIR`?

Comment: Please read the error message carefully. Some typos (uppercase instead of lowercase, number 1 instead of letter l) can be hard to spot. Also, make sure the code you attempt to load does not depend on resources that are not available at that point (e.g., a global variable).

Comment: ../web-app/app/libraries/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php - I have hardcoded this into other areas of the script and it is included without problems.

Comment: I'm convinced that this problem is specific to the shutdown function. The file location is 100% correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write to file with register\_shutdown\_function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861606/write-to-file-with-register-shutdown-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your comments suggest you're using a *relative* path:

```
../web-app/app/libraries/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php
^^
```

That's generally unreliable in the PHP universe but in [this particular case](https://www.php.net/register_shutdown_function):

> Working directory of the script can change inside the shutdown function under some web servers, e.g. Apache.

If the error message doesn't display the full path, you can at least [print current directory](http://php.net/getcwd) yourself for debugging purposes:

```
var_dump(getcwd());
```

Comment: Thanks that's useful, inside the shutdown function the path output is 'C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4'.. how is this possible?

Comment: As I said, using relative paths for file handling is nor a robust technique. In practice, I've found it easier to use absolute paths (often building them dynamically from current *file*: `__FILE__` or `__DIR__`).

Comment: Yes relative path are not a good practice, but some (old) frameworks like CodeIgniter 2 uses that.

Answer (score 3):

As [PHP doucmentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) in `Notes` section:

> Working directory of the script can change inside the shutdown function under some web servers, e.g. Apache.

I'm not sure but maybe It makes that the file could not be found.

Use ABSOLUTE paths to files instead of relative in shutdown functions. Because when script processing is complete current working directory changes.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution in this thread [Write to file with register_shutdown_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861606/write-to-file-with-register-shutdown-function)

I needed to set a working directory constant before the function is called and then switch back to that directory inside the shutdown function.

```
define('WORKING_DIRECTORY', getcwd());

function shutdown()
{
    chdir(WORKING_DIRECTORY);
    //files can now be included relative to the application
}
```

Comment: When you find that a question is a duplicate it's recommended to flag it as such so we don't get the same answers scattered all around the site.