# Call a specific function before request ends

Tags: php

I have a PHP application and would like to call a specific function (this function writes information into a log file) at the end of the request. Effectively I would like this function to be called last, no matter what route the code took and no matter what functions were called previously.

Is there a way to know or find out when PHP is just about ready to send back info to the web server?

```
function req_end() {
    global $logger;
    $logger->log("----------------------------------------------", PEAR_LOG_INFO);
    $logger->log("                 Request End                  ", PEAR_LOG_INFO);
    $logger->log("==============================================", PEAR_LOG_INFO);
    $logger->log("", PEAR_LOG_INFO);
}
register_shutdown_function('req_end');
```

If I call req_end at the end of my index.php file, then it writes the logs, if not, it isn't called at all.
Thank you
Crouz

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

It runs a function whenever the script finishes, even if it's with an `exit()`

This is an example copied from the documentation:

```
<?php
function shutdown()
{
    // This is our shutdown function, in 
    // here we can do any last operations
    // before the script is complete.

    echo 'Script executed with success', PHP_EOL;
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew about this function but thought it wasn't the right one because although I call it with the name of my function which writes to logs, nothing happens, the logs are not written to. So basically, it is not working for me for some reason.

Comment: But does your function runs ? If so, you should change your question, as your problem is related to writing into a log file, not firing a function at the script's end. BTW you could show your code to write that log File, I'm sure you are just putting the path wrong or some small mistake, try using an absolute path for example.

Comment: The function runs if I call it manually, but not if called by using register_shutdown_function. I have even written another function to simply echo something and then registered it with register_shutdown_function, and it doesn't get called either. I have read that this functionality can be turned off in the php config file, but I haven't got a clue what to look for, so I'll have to do some searching on this.

Comment: You should have pasted more code to let people help you, like, people won't know what do `$logger` and its method `$logger->log` do exactly, maybe it was just your logging function which was wrong, not the register_shutdown_function at all xD

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found out what was wrong.
The problem is described here in details: [Write to file with register_shutdown_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861606/write-to-file-with-register-shutdown-function)

I will attempt the remedy in this post, if not I will have to call the functiona manually myself.

Regards
Crouz

Comment: Indeed, by using the technique described in the post provided above, everything works fine. I thought I was going mad for a while.